# Decorators with different constructor arguments

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, decorator

Using Castle Windsor, I'd like to create a class that records an integer.  But I'd like to decorate it several times with other classes.  I can see how this works if all concretes involved have dependencies that can be resolved, but that's not the case here.  Consider this code:

```
public interface IRecorder
{
    void Add(int value);
}

public class NotifyingRecorder : IRecorder
{
    readonly IRecorder decoratedRecorder;

    public NotifyingRecorder(IRecorder decoratedRecorder)
    {
        this.decoratedRecorder = decoratedRecorder;
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        decoratedRecorder.Add(value);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Added " + value);
    }
}

public class ModelUpdatingRecorder : IRecorder
{
    int seed;

    public ModelUpdatingRecorder(int seed)
    {
        this.seed = seed;
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        seed += value;
    }
}
```

And registered with:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRecorder>().ImplementedBy<NotifyingRecorder>());
container.Register(Component.For<IRecorder>().ImplementedBy<ModelUpdatingRecorder>());
```

Resolving an `IRecorder` will never work here, since `ModelUpdatingRecorder` has a non-optional dependency.  I cannot use a static dependency since `seed` is not known at compile-time.

Is there a way to specify the `seed` parameter at runtime and have the decoration still work?

*This code sample is a simplification of my scenario, but the idea is the same.  I have decorators, and the lowest one relies on a specific value/instance to be provided to it.*

Comment: So, decorators aside, how would you supply the dependency at run time?

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt Via a factory, typically from the [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor).

Comment: As far as I'm aware supplying non-optional dependencies at run-time can either be done via factory methods (as you're suggesting) or wiring the container so that the dependency is retrieved via some global (static) storage. As far as I know the latter is the only out-of-the-box mechanism if the dependency exists on some sub-dependency of the component being resolved. Wiser heads than mine might be able to contradict this, so I'll watch this question with interest.

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt See my answer, I've found a way to get it done.  Whether or not it's _the_ way is another matter...

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that I believe is the way this should be done.  Down in the innards of Windsor the `DefaultDependencyResolver` has a method it uses to resolve sub-dependencies (such as a decorated instance of `IRecorder` above) called [`RebuildContextForParameter`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/Resolvers/DefaultDependencyResolver.cs#L184).  It calls this to create a new context to use when resolving the dependency (i.e. the parameter to the constructor).  The method is:

```
/// <summary>This method rebuild the context for the parameter type. Naive implementation.</summary>
protected virtual CreationContext RebuildContextForParameter(CreationContext current, Type parameterType)
{
    if (parameterType.ContainsGenericParameters)
    {
        return current;
    }

    return new CreationContext(parameterType, current, false);
}
```

The `false` parameter in `CreationContext` constructor is `propagateInlineDependencies`, which when true will copy over the `current` context's `AdditionalArguments`, thereby passing down the parameters to the sub-dependencies.

To flip this `false` to `true`, create a new class that derives from `DefaultDependencyResolver`:

```
public class DefaultDependencyResolverInheritContext : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    protected override CreationContext RebuildContextForParameter(CreationContext current, Type parameterType)
    {
        if (parameterType.ContainsGenericParameters)
        {
            return current;
        }

        return new CreationContext(parameterType, current, true);
    }
}
```

Then use that when creating the Windsor container:

```
var kernel = new DefaultKernel(
                 new DefaultDependencyResolverInheritContext(), 
                 new NotSupportedProxyFactory());
var container = new WindsorContainer(kernel, new DefaultComponentInstaller());
```

The `NotSupportedProxyFactory` and `DefaultComponentInstaller` are the defaults when using the parameter-less constructors for `DefaultKernel` and `WindsorContainer`.

When done, the code above will work when a factory is used to create an `IRecorder`, i.e.:

```
// during type registration/bootstrapping
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(Component.For<IRecorder>().ImplementedBy<NotifyingRecorder>());
container.Register(Component.For<IRecorder>().ImplementedBy<ModelUpdatingRecorder>());
container.Register(Component.For<IRecorderFactory>().AsFactory());
```

Where `IRecorderFactory` is:

```
public interface IRecorderFactory
{
    IRecorder Create(int seed);
}
```

Then this will work as expected:

```
IRecorderFactory recorderFactory = container.Resolve<IRecorderFactory>();
IRecorder recorder = recorderFactory.Create(20);
recorder.Add(6);
```

Hopefully that helps others!

Comment: I've seen this work before Patrick. It will certainly produce the result you're looking for in this case. The problem is that parameters passed to a resolve call are non-specific in terms of the dependency they are intended for . They can be utilised for every optional and mandatory subdependency anywhere in the tree. For complex component/dependency trees the risk is that it becomes a big ball of mud.

Comment: I agree @PhilDegenhardt. If you have multiple decorators they all get this kind of seed, which may be completely redundant in most decorators, while it is only needed in a few.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the seed in an interface (`ISeedHolder` ?) and register it with a singleton lifestyle. Then use the interface in your `ModelUpdatingRecorder` instead of the raw int. Unless your seeds may need to be parallelized it should allow you to set the seed and resolve it when constructing the `ModelUpdatingRecorder`

```
public interface ISeedHolder
{
    int Seed {get;set;}
}

public class ModelUpdatingRecorder : IRecorder
{
    int seed;

    public ModelUpdatingRecorder(ISeedHolder seedHolder)
    {
        this.seed = seedHolder.Seed;
    }
```

Would this solution achieve what you need?

Comment: This just defers the problem.  I need to give `ModelUpdatingRecord` a specific instance of `ISeedHolder` (i.e. one with a particular seed value), and doing this has the same problem as the original question.

Comment: If the `ISeedHolder` is defined as singleton, you have access to what data will be fed into the `ModelUpdatingRecord`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, but global context is what I'm trying to avoid.  I could have several of these created across threads, and coordinating that work with a singleton involved is not something I want to do.

Comment: That's what i was meaning when i was talking about parallelizing seeds. You can define your own context in Castle.Windsor. If a perThread lifestyle doesn't work out for you it is possible to customize the lifestyle: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx#Custom_lifestyles_17

Comment: A custom lifestyle is something I hadn't considered yet, I'll need to think if I can reasonably define the context in which I need these objects.  If I can then I think that may be the way to go.