# Using same parameter value in a dependency with Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Not even sure this can be done and may need to re-think the whole thing, however thought I would ask before doing that.

Ok I have a repository class with the following constructor

```
    public Repository(ISessionManager sessionManager, string dbName)
    {
        this.sessionManager = sessionManager;
        this.dbName = dbName;
    }
```

At present anywhere in the application that needs to use a repository it uses dependency injection and the repository are registered with the container like so.

```
Component.For<IRepository<User, int>>().ImplementedBy<Repository<User, int>>()
                     .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("dbName", "admin")),
```

What I am looking to do is push the setting of the database name up a level to the services which will use the repositories.

For example having a service with the constructor

```
public SecurityService(ITransactionFactory transactionFactory,
                       IRepository<User, int> userRepository,
                       string dbName)
```

I want the argument dbName to be registered with the container against ServiceService and have that value passed when injecting the argument userRepository.

So if another service needs to use the same repository with a different database then when it is registered a new name is provided.

Is this possible?

Comment: [This is a possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22690848/1698557).  Otherwise, you could create a [factory](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md) for `IRepository` that takes the dbName as an argument and inject it into `SecurityService` and then create the repository manually with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way that I'm aware of to do exactly what you're looking for, but using named registrations may get you to the same end-goal in a way that's a bit more Windsor-"correct".

For instance, the following two registrations could live in tandem:

```
Component.For<IRepository<User, int>>()
         .ImplementedBy<Repository<User, int>>()
         .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("dbName", "admin")
         .Named("adminRepositoryRegistration")

Component.For<IRepository<User, int>>()
         .ImplementedBy<Repository<User, int>>()
         .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("dbName", "user")
         .Named("userRepositoryRegistration")
```

Then you could wire up your services to depend on the particular registrations in Windsor. For instance, this one would be bound to the first registration:

```
Component.For<IUserService>()
         .ImplementedBy<UserService>()
         .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("userRepository", "userRepositoryRegistration")
```

and this will bind to the second:

```
Component.For<ISecurityService>()
         .ImplementedBy<SecurityService>()
         .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("adminRepository", "adminRepositoryRegistration")
```

Overall I feel like it gives a bit cleaner of a solution, since it handles *all* of the dependency provisioning in the DI registration instead of leaving any loose ends to wrap up in the actual services, and allows you to route dependencies as needed.

Comment: . is the way I went in the end and seems like then only way to do it. Will probably never have to do this again