# How to pass an argument to the constructor of a 'child' item of the to-be-resolved type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm trying to find out the best (nicest) way to pass an argument to the constructor of a child object of an auto-resolved parameter.

Why?
Because I have a program that does almost all its computations against the same "production" database (defined in the config file, so no argument required). But now needs to run some work on a 'copy' of this database. Therefore requiring a different connection string.

The connection string can be supplied on the constructor, and is not known at compile time. The problem is that I can't (or do not know how to) simply access this constructor because it is buried deep inside the generated items.

Consider the following (simplified) code snippet:

```
public class Example
{
    protected readonly IGenerateSomethingFactory Factory;
    public Example(IGenerateSomethingFactory factory)
    {
        Factory = factory;
    }

    public Task DoSomething(string ConnectionString, string a, string b)
    {
        //needs to run somehow using the supplied connection string ...
        return Task.Run(() => Factory.CreateSomething().Execute(a, b));
        //= Task.Run(() => new Something(new UnitOfWork(new DataContext(ConnectionString))).Execute(a, b));
    }

    public Task DoSomething(string a, string b)
    {
        //needs to run using the default connection string (defined in config)
        return Task.Run(() => Factory.CreateSomething().Execute(a, b));
    }
}
```

The problem lays in the first `DoSomething(...)` function.

Note: The Castle Windsor installer looks like this:

```
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        container.Register(Component.For<IGenerateSomethingFactory>().AsFactory());
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().InNamespace("x").WithService.FirstInterface());
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a solution that:

- is thread safe
- is easy to understand (if not easy to think of)
- allows refactoring (so no named arguments like "conString" )
- does not require changes to other non-relevant code
  (i.e. setting properties public ... )
- does not call `new` or `container.Resolve<>()`

I have been looking into selection handlers, but have not really found what I was looking for.

PS: I'm using Castle Windsor 3.3.0

PPS: this is my first question, I can provide more example code but thought I should restrict to the minimum ... so let me know if I need to do so.

Comment: It seems you could just add `ConnectionString` as a parameter to your factory's `CreateSomething` method.  Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: Well I did not create the factory, it is auto generated by Castle Windsor. Also, then I would probably need to call Resolve<X> on the container and make sure I do all the cleanup properly. And I'm new to DI ...

Comment: Right but you defined the interface.  Read [this section](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#resolving-with-arguments) and [this section](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#method-parameters-are-forwarded-to-the-caller-by-name) from the wiki.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to pass these constructor arguments down the chain? This seems like a pretty glaring issue that I can't find a solution for.

Comment: @DanQ: No we eventually modified the service to allow setting the parameter after creating it. Not optimal, because we don't want to allow to change it after first time use.

Comment: Check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48345449/2029835

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, it looks like all you need to do is add a parameter to your [typed factory's](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md) `CreateSomething` method:

```
public interface IGenerateSomethingFactory
{
    ISomething CreateSomething(string connectionString);
}
```

Then add that as a parameter to your `ISomething` implementation:

```
public class Something : ISomething
{
    public Something(string connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

Note how the parameter to `CreateSomething` and `Something`'s constructor are named the same.  [This is the default behavior for parameter matching](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#method-parameters-are-forwarded-to-the-caller-by-name).

Now, you just pass the value along in your call to `DoSomething`:

```
public Task DoSomething(string ConnectionString, string a, string b)
{
    return Task.Run(() => Factory.CreateSomething(ConnectionString).Execute(a, b));
}
```

---

Based on your added code, what you're trying to do isn't immediately possible.  In a nutshell, you have this resolution hierarchy:

- `IGenerateSomethingFactory.Create(string constring)`

  - `Something.ctor(IUnitOfWork uow)`

    - `UnitOfWork.ctor(IDataContext context)`

      - `DataContext.ctor(string constring)`

You're trying to pass the argument from the call to `Create` down to the constructor of `DataContext`.

For a way to enable this, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22690848/1698557) (to my own question). I do this by changing the default behavior of Windsor to pass the factory creation parameters down to all objects being resolved instead of just the first.

First, create this class to change this behavior:

```
public class DefaultDependencyResolverInheritContext : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    protected override CreationContext RebuildContextForParameter(CreationContext current, Type parameterType)
    {
        if (parameterType.ContainsGenericParameters)
        {
            return current;
        }

        return new CreationContext(parameterType, current, true);
    }
}
```

Then supply it when creating the container:

```
var kernel = new DefaultKernel(
                 new DefaultDependencyResolverInheritContext(), 
                 new NotSupportedProxyFactory());
var container = new WindsorContainer(kernel, new DefaultComponentInstaller());
```

That's it.  Now when you call your `Create` method, the `constring` parameter will be passed down to all objects being registered.  *Obviously this can cause problems if you have parameters that are the same name!*  In your case, this is an "ambient" parameter (my term) so you could just document this behavior/parameter name and call it a day.

I'd love to see another approach to this, save for creating factories for all the intermediate types.

Comment: I have just tried this and it does not work. I thought this would only work for parameters of the object you want to resolve, and that they are not passed through to other objects further down the road ...
(Tested using a break point in both constructors, the constructor with the string parameter is never hit)

Comment: You'll need to add a bit more code then.  You're testing with something that you didn't post a equivalent example of.

Comment: I have pasted all test classes on paste bin [link](http://pastebin.com/TitQv3uN) I have added break points to lines 77 & 81 and stepped into the Example.Run() method.
PS: If this is the code you want/need to answer I will update the question with this code.

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't think I will change the default because I'm new to this project where I need it for and don't know for sure if it would cause problems. I'm still going to wait a little to see if someone else has another approach to this.

Comment: It seems there are no other ideas on the matter for now, so I guess that means that your answer is indeed the answer. Thanks for the help Patrick.

Comment: That's awesome and has just made my headache go away :) Have a +1